# How to close windows in Squish IDE (Python) to automate URL checks

Tags: python, ide, window, squish

I want to use Squish to automate a series of tests that involves visiting many URLs in separate windows.

Is there an easy way to close the current window?

I have a simple loop setup as follows:

```
for url in testlist:
    loadUrl(url)
    #Do some tests
```

I just need one more line to close the window, before the loop does another iteration and repeats the tests on the next url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the right version of Squish to test this solution, so my code may not work I am more suggesting an idea.

Can you perhaps use the Squish Web API function [evalJS();](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.0/rgs-webconvenience.html#web-evalJS-function) to call the JS self.close() function.

It may be something like:

```
evalJS("self.close();")
```